# Adding an product page on asp.net website like www.domain.com/product

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-server

I have a product page website developed in asp.net with MVC 5. I want it locate at www.domain.com/product. But as I try to do that its not working. Its working fine when I upload it to subdomain on my server as product.domain.com but not as www.domain.com/product. I have a windows server. What can I do to locate it at www.domain.com/product.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder under the IIS root folder and mark it as an application on IIS (or on IIS create an application under the domain node) and deploy there.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your routes to have product/ in it. Something like:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "product/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```